# Why do I get stuck in a compile loop - Lambda

Tags: swift, function, lambda

Why do I get stuck in a compile loop in Playground when trying to run the following?

```
func makeIncrementer(byHowMuch: Int) -> ((Int) -> Int) {
    func addArg(number: Int) -> Int {
        return 2 + number
    }
    return addArg
}
var twoTimesIncrementer = makeIncrementer(2)
twoTimesIncrementer(7)
```

Also, how do you call a function returning a function in a non-functional language? Lambda still?

Comment: Do you have an example of a non-functional language where you can define functions that return functions?

Comment: Function returning another function or taking one as argument is [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I do not get stuck in a compile loop, it returns 9 as expected. And Playground has its fair amount of bugs, if something does not work in playground, stick it into an actual project, try to run it and there you will see wether or not it actually works.

Secondly a function returning a function is simply still a function, its naming does not change with its return type. The only thing to note is that in Swift you can have functions as First-Class Objects, your `twoTimesIncrementer` is a variable as any other.

Other than that my recommendation is not trying to get over-obsessed with the naming of certain patterns or features. Do you have an example of a non-functional language where you can define functions that return functions?

Comment: I meant not strictly functional. Swift is object oriented for the most part, after all. Thanks for clearing that up. Perhaps my macbook air 2011 is just too old for Swift, if its not an issue with the playground; I will try that in a different environment.